# I can't figure out how to displace lines based on height from an image. Is geometry nodes the answer?

Tags: geometry-nodes, displacement, shrinkwrap

I'm modeling a mountain and am trying to add trails to the top of it. I was able to displace the square mesh to form the mountain based on an image (bottom left of the first pic). However, when I tried to repeat it for the trails mesh (only vertices and edges) it doesn't work right.

**Pic 1** - Correct displacement with an image for reference
[image: pic 1]

**Pic 2** - The second mesh I'm trying to displace.
[image: pic 2]

As I searched for an answer, it seems like geometry nodes are the way to do it. Especially if I convert the mesh in Pic 2 to a curve. I've tried to learn how to use geometry nodes well enough to do it, but they're very weird to me and I haven't gotten it to work.

Does anyone have an idea of how to do this? With or without geometry nodes, just looking for any kind of answer. Otherwise, I have to move each vertex to the right spot by hand and it's really time-consuming.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: How was the mesh trail on the 2nd pic created?

Comment: You can try shrinkwrap modifier to deform the second object onto the mountain

Comment: Since you create the displacement with a shader, you have no chance to use the mesh with Geometry Nodes. However, if you create the displacement with GN (or another modifier), then it can also be solved with GN.